# Number of columns required to reach a minimum sum, by row

Tags: r

I have a data frame with rows as time and columns as principal components

(PC1 to PC10). An example can be found in the answer provided here: [Rolling PCA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616427/rolling-pca-and-plotting-proportional-variance-of-principal-components)

For each row, I want to extract the number of PC required to reach a minimum sum of 0.90. In the example table, for every row, summing over three columns gives a minimum of 0.90; so I want to extract the number 3 into a separate column. In my specific case, the number of columns required to reach 0.9 varies by row.

An example of the result I want is in the last column (PC_N).

[image]

Comment: can you do a little example with expected outcome?

Comment: I just added a table to show the answer I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data: (you should provide ready to use data)

```
set.seed(1337)    
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(6*4), 6, 4))
```

code:

```
df1$PC_N <-
    apply(df1[1:4], 1, function(x) {which(cumsum(x) >= .9)[1]})
```

result:

```
#         V1        V2         V3        V4 PC_N
#1 0.8455612 0.5753591 0.04045594 0.1168015    2
#2 0.3623455 0.7868502 0.34512398 0.5304800    2
#3 0.9092146 0.5210399 0.48515698 0.2770135    1
#4 0.6730770 0.1798602 0.45335329 0.7649627    3
#5 0.3068619 0.3963743 0.98232933 0.9653852    3
#6 0.2104455 0.7860896 0.42140667 0.7954002    2
```

further detail:

```
apply(    # use apply over rows (1)
df1[1:4], # apply only on PC1 to PC4 (first to 4th col)
1,        # go row-wise
function(x) {
which(cumsum(x) >= .9)[1]  # get first index of the cummulated sum that is at least 0.9
})        # the end
```

make sure you further read about the functions used: e.g. `?which`, `?apply` ...

Comment: I like your solution better than mine. May I only suggest `cumsum(sort(x, decreasing = T))` to generalise for cases where the elements are not sorted in decreasing value?

Comment: no, I leave it up to the end-user to input sorted data or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a function that returns the number of elements of a vector needed to add up to at least .9, na.rm = T and then apply it row-wise to the appropriate columns of df:

```
get.length <- function(x) {
  ind <- which.max(x)
  sum <- max(x)
  if (sum >= .9) {
    return(1)
  } else {
    while (sum < .9 & length(ind) != length(x)) {
      ind <- c(ind, which.max(x[-ind]))
      sum <- sum(x[ind], na.rm = T)
    }
  }
  if (sum < .9) return(NA) else return(length(ind))
}
```

The function looks for maximum value of a vector and if it's less than .9 adds the next largest and repeats. Once .9 is reached it returns the number of elements needed to sum up to at least .9. If they don't, it returns `NA`.

Note. Even though your PCs will decrease in value, the function works even if the elements are not sorted in decreasing order.

You can apply the function to the column indices of your data frame `df` like this:

```
apply(df[ , col_indices], 1, get.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are likely to have a `prcomp` object rather than a dataframe, but no matter

```
exampldf <- data.frame(PC1 = c(0.97, 0.40, 0.85, 0.75),
                       PC2 = c(0.01, 0.20, 0.10, 0.10),
                       PC3 = c(0.01, 0.20, 0.03, 0.10),
                       PC4 = c(0.01, 0.20, 0.02, 0.05))
rownames(exampldf) <- c("WEEK1", "WEEK2", "WEEK3", "WEEK4")
library(matrixStats)
exampldf$PC_N <- 1 + rowSums(rowCumsums(as.matrix(exampldf)) < 0.9)
```

produces

```
> exampldf
       PC1  PC2  PC3  PC4 PC_N
WEEK1 0.97 0.01 0.01 0.01    1
WEEK2 0.40 0.20 0.20 0.20    4
WEEK3 0.85 0.10 0.03 0.02    2
WEEK4 0.75 0.10 0.10 0.05    3
```